# chart.js Is there way to color line chart ticks depending on value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have simple chart.js line chart:
[image]

I need to color lines between ticks, depending on previous value like that:

[image]

If next value is lower than prev line must be red, if higher color is green.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following solution.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
//adding custom chart type
Chart.defaults.multicolorLine = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.multicolorLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function(ease) {
    var
      startIndex = 0,
      meta = this.getMeta(),
      points = meta.data || [],
      colors = this.getDataset().colors,
      area = this.chart.chartArea,
      originalDatasets = meta.dataset._children
        .filter(function(data) {
          return !isNaN(data._view.y);
        });

    function _setColor(newColor, meta) {
      meta.dataset._view.borderColor = newColor;
    }

    if (!colors) {
      Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
      return;
    }

    for (var i = 2; i <= colors.length; i++) {
      if (colors[i-1] !== colors[i]) {
        _setColor(colors[i-1], meta);
        meta.dataset._children = originalDatasets.slice(startIndex, i);
        meta.dataset.draw();
        startIndex = i - 1;
      }
    }

    meta.dataset._children = originalDatasets.slice(startIndex);
    meta.dataset.draw();
    meta.dataset._children = originalDatasets;

    points.forEach(function(point) {
      point.draw(area);
    });
  }
});
// build colors sequence
const data = [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45];
const availableColors = ['red', 'green'];
let colors = [];
data.forEach(item => {
  availableColors.forEach(color => {
    colors.push(color)
  })
})

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'multicolorLine',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: data,
            //first color is not important
            colors: ['', ...colors]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```